# How to Handle last chunk of large File with java or scala

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, java-8

Pretty simple question , Suppose I have a large file,
My purpose is to read every 200 lines and make some process on different thread. The File is pretty long so the last thread won't get exactly 200 lines.

I thought something about: ( but didn't get how to solve the remaining last chunk....)

```
String[] chunk = new String[200];
        int count = 0;
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            chunk[count % chunk.length] = line;
            count++;
            if (count % chunk.length == 0) {
                exec.execute(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO process what ever

                    }
                });
            }

        }
```

PORPOSE:
Write code to handle each Chunk of lines on different thread with consideration of last chunk , with the best performance/optimization.

P.S - not to read tho whole file first and store in memory chunked...I think do it during iteration...

Answer (score 1):

```
      Source
        .fromFile("fileName")
        .getLines
        .grouped(200)
        .foreach(doStuff)
```

Comment: `Future(doStuff(_))` to address the thread part of the question.

Comment: Hi, as you suggest , is it good to parse to whole file grouped into memory.... ? I thought to iterate over chunks so each chunk make some Future...but what with the last ?

Comment: @VitalyT, if the file is really big, processing it in bunches might be a good idea. And this is what this solution actually does! `Source.getLines` returns an `Iterator[String]` which is lazy i.e. doesn't read data until it is asked for more (except for IO buffering which is also good for performance).

Comment: wow cool as i see this is Scala , I tried to find solution in java8 , maybe you can help , didn't find in java8 grouping lines from file...:(

Answer (score 0):

This is a usual case when you process something in equal parts, the last part will be smaller than the chunk size but bigger than 0 excluding the case where `tot_lines % chunk_size == 0`. What you can do is run a new final thread after the while loop has ended. In the `chunk` array you will have the remaining lines.